# Is Elasticsearch X-Pack able to return graph vertices across different types?

Tags: elasticsearch, graph-databases, xpack

I have `product` type data loaded into Elasticsearch containing `catalogue_number` and `name`. I also have `customer` data loaded into Elasticsearch containing `name` and `purchases` (where purchases is an array of product numbers).

For example:

```
CATALOGUE_NUMBER, NAME
518, "Toilet Paper"
388, "Candy Bar"
263, "Carrots"
```

And, for customers:

```
NAME, PURCHASES
"Jack", [518, 388]
"John", [263]
"Bill", [263, 518]
```

Considering the relationship is many to one (i.e. customers purchase many items), am I able to use Kibana to view a graph linking purchases to specific customers, or is this out of scope?

My end goal is to have a graph showing `product` and `customer` as vertices and edges showing which products each customer purchases. I am very confused as to whether Elasticsearch is capable, or if I should move to a pure graph database such as Neo4J and Elasticsearch for searching only.

Answer (score 0):

The Graph feature can draw out these connections if they share a common field name - the unique identity of a node is a field name and a term. Terms can be in different indices but as long as they share a common field name they are seen as the same node.
I'm not sure which business problem you are trying to solve (recommendations? Fraud?) but depending on what you are trying to achieve you may want to model things differently.
If you're interested in recommendations and people who-bought-X-also-bought-Y style suggestions then the people are unlikely to be interesting nodes to plot and you can just examine the "purchases" field which will draw out which products significantly co-occur.
For more detailed "forensic" type applications you may want to just have person->product links and not have product->product links in which case you would be forced to create more classical "edge-like" documents with only 2 nodes - a person ID and a product ID.